# Error in Angular and RXJS promise

Tags: angular, promise, observable, rxjs5

I'm looking to upgrade an Angular application from 2 to 4, and I'm getting the following error:

```
 Type 'Promise<void | Store>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Store>'.
```

Type 'void | Store' is not assignable to type 'Store'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Store'.

The line in question is this:

```
return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as Store)
            .catch((err) => { console.log('An error occurred under StoreService.StoreGetById', err); });
```

This worked before I upgraded, and I'm fairly new to RxJS.

Comment: It's not an RxJS issue; it's a TypeScript issue. And the `Promise<void | Store>` type more accurately conveys the situation. Your `catch` swallows the error and returns nothing - hence the `void`. There are two possible paths: one that resolves to a `Store`; and another that resolves to `void`. I would resolve the problem by re-throwing the error, as what's the point in swallowing it only to have a reference error occur thereafter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise rejections are logged automatically - like the comment by cartant explains - by `.catch`ing an error you're causing the `| Void`.

When a JavaScript function doesn't return anything it returns `undefined` by default - so your promise is either for the store (from the `then`) or void (from the `catch`).

The correct solution IMO would be to completely remove the `.catch` clause and rely on promise rejections being logged to your console automatically anyway.